# Using es6 to set axios.defaults in Vue but doesn't work

Tags: ecmascript-6, vue.js, axios

I'm new to es6.I'm trying to use es6 to set axios's defaults like this,it works

```
import qs from 'querystring'

let config = {
    baseURL: 'http://127.0.0.7',
    transformRequest: [function (data) {
        return qs.stringify(data)
    }],
}

Vue.http.defaults = Object.assign(Vue.http.defaults, config)
```

but when I set it as `Vue.http.defaults = Object.assign({}, Vue.http.defaults, config)`or`Vue.http.defaults = {...Vue.http.defaults, ...config}`,axios can't get the correct value

what the problem with it?

Comment: `Object.assign(Vue.http.defaults, config)` and `Object.assign({}, Vue.http.defaults, axiosConf)` _should_ be functionally equivalent unless something was maintaining a reference to `Vue.http.defaults` though I can't think why anything would

Comment: What **exactly** do you mean by _"axios can't get the correct value"_? How are you verifying the issue?

Comment: Also, axios isn't aware of anything Vue related and Vue has no standard AJAX / HTTP implementation. How are you using `Vue.http.defaults` with axios?

Comment: Well,I defines`Vue.http = axios`globally.If I `console.log(1)`in transformRequest using `Object.assign(Vue.http.defaults, config)`,it will be print '1' when I use axios.post,but it won't print '1' when I use `Object.assign({}, Vue.http.defaults, config)`

Comment: In that case, see my first comment. Axios must maintain certain references to its original [config defaults](https://github.com/axios/axios#config-defaults). Overwriting the `defaults` object will not apply to those existing references

Comment: @Phil so it's the problem that some attribute couldn't be copied by `Object.assign()`,is it?

Comment: @KiraYosikage no. I'd have to look through the source code but say some part internal to axios has `let config = this.defaults`. When you assign a new value to `axios.defaults`, that `config` variable still points to the old value. If however you set `axios.defaults.prop = val` instead, then `config.prop` refers to the same value. **Bottom line, don't overwrite `axios.defaults`**

Comment: @Phil understand.Thank you very much